# Convert JS Regex to PHP Regex

Tags: php, javascript, regex

My understanding of Regex isn't great and I need to adapt my working JS code to PHP.

This is one of the run-throughs in JavaScript (it finds hashtags and makes HTML anchor tags out of them):

```
exp = /(^|\s)#(\w+)/g;
messagetext = messagetext.replace(exp, "$1<a class='myHashtag' href='http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2' target='_blank'>#$2</a>");
```

How would this be done in PHP?

Comment: using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace), for starters

Comment: The documentation is quite a helpful resource, a Google search is all it takes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$messagetext = preg_replace('~^\h*+#\K\w++~m',
  '<a class="myHashtag" '
 .'href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$0" target="_blank">#$0</a>',
  $messagetext);
```

pattern detail:

```
^       # line's begining
\h*+    # horizontal space (ie space or tab), zero or more times (possessive)
#       # literal #
\K      # forgets all the begining!
\w++    # [a-zA-Z0-9_] one or more times (possessive)
```

Delimiters are `~` but you can choose other characters.

I use the *multiline mode* (*m* modifier), thus `^` stands for line's begining.

*(possessive)* indicates to the regex engine that it don't need to backtrack by adding a `+` after a quantifier. The subpattern becomes then more efficient.

Comment: Actually, is it possible to do this using my original regexp? My expression didn't include the `#`, which was important. I could run another function to remove the `#` afterwards, but I'd like to avoid that...

Comment: @tylerl, you can use exactly the same regex in PHP as your JS regex without modifications. That you even ask this without trying... See comments on your question.

Comment: @tyler: as Qtax say, you can use your regex and replacement, but note that my expression don't include the # too cause i use the \K trick.

Comment: Ahhh! I see now, I guess (late!) last night when I tried it I gave up with my regexp when it was producing completely blank text - I tried it again and removed the g at the end... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tylerl: the g modifier doesn't exist in php, `preg_replace` does a global search.